# Task-Based Parallelism in D

Tags: api, concurrency, parallel-processing, task, d

Does the programming language D support task-based parallelism in any way, either natively or through some API?

Answer (score 11):

check out the *obviously* named [parallelism module](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html)